# React.net bundle and minification ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, babeljs

I'm using React.net, more specific the `System.Web.Optimization.React` library.

I create a virtual path and a put several files on it:

```
bundles.Add(new BabelBundle(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2).Include(
    (...)
));
```

Then, I import the files in the `cshtml` by using the following line:

```
@Scripts.Render(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.Libs.All)
```

And an error `Out Of Memory` is throwing:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 13:
>   @Html.Raw(ItemsHelper.JSGlobalVariables.GetGlobalVariablesArrayJavascript())
>   Line 14:     @Styles.Render(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2CSS.Root) Line
>   15:     @Scripts.Render(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2) Line
>   16:  Line 17:
>   @Scripts.Render(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV1.Shared,
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Repository\Default\adigitalbook\html5\adigitalbook.html5.mainserver\Views\Shared\LayoutEditorV2.cshtml
>   Line: 15

If I change the way that I import the files to not use the Babel to Transform the files (as follows) the error not persists.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2).Include(
    (...)
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was divide the number of files that each virtual path has, so the visual studio could transform and minifying the files without any problem.

Another possible solution is to check the option on visual studio 2017 Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web projects -> "Use the 64bits version of IIS Express for web sites and project". My concern with this solution it that if you publish your software on a machine that does not support 64 bits, maybe the error will appear again.